# Unity Joystick method C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, joystick

I'm using Unity, and am trying to use the Joystick namespace. but whenever I try to declare a joystic it says the namespace isn't valid.

Here are the libraries I am using:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using Riverscout;
```

And this is the code that gives me the error:

```
    public Joystick moveJoystick;
```

Can anyone tell me what library I need to use to make this work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Riverscout is used for a Lat Lon converter much further on in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UnityEngine` namespace doesn't contain any class named `Joystick`.

You can, however, access joystick input that has been [set up in the Input Manager](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html) by querying [`Input.GetAxis()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html).

Suppose you set up a joystick to control two axes, named "Joy0x" and "Joy0y", you could then get the input like so:

```
function Update() {
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Joy0x");
    var y = Input.GetAxis("Joy0y");
    transform.Rotate(x, y, 0); //rotate attached GameObject
}
```

I imagine many people have posted joystick helper scripts. If you're working with one of those, please mention it.

Answer (score 1):

Joystick.js is included in Standard Assets (Mobile) package. It's also used by a plethora of other 3rd party Unity Developers such as EasyTouch, EasyJoystick, Touch UI, UI Touch, and countless others. But natively the Unity3D namespace doesn't contain Joystick like @rutter said.